# MacBook Pro 13" (2010) clean install

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, installation, macbook

I'm having a problem doing a clean install on my MacBook Pro 13" (2010). When I put in the OS X Snow Leopard 10.6 disc, I end up on a screen in different languages saying I need to shut off and turn on my computer. Can anyone help me with this?

Here's what I got:

```
  System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 10.4.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
  Time since boot: 5:31


  Chipset Model: NVIDIA GeForce 320M
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCI
  VRAM (Total): 256 MB
  Vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID: 0x08a0
  Revision ID: 0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3533
  Displays:
  Color LCD:
  Resolution: 1280 x 800
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Built-In: Yes
  Display Connector:
  Status: No Display Connected

  System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 10.4.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
```

Comment: Is this the software install disc that came with your computer or a retail Mac OS X 10.6 disc?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you used the wrong disk. Do you mean this message: [image: Kernel Panic]

The last time i used a disc that was delivered with another machine for installing the OS on my MacBook i got the same error. I think this was because i tried to start a Intel Mac from a disk for a PPC Mac (or the other way round? don't know - doesn't matter).

If it's not that problem, then the disk may be damaged (unlikely) or your MacBook is damaged itself. The latter is more likely, since you are already having problems. What kind of problems, by the way?

Try to boot up your mac from the "Applications Install Disc 2" while holding the <kbd>D</kbd>-key. And run a quick test and a full test if the quick test yields no errors. The whole Process is documented [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509)

Comment: According to EveryMac.com, both the [2.4GHz](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) and [2.66GHz](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.66-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) MacBook Pro 13" models released in mid-2010 shipped with Mac OS X v10.6.3 (build 10D2125) -- anything older (e.g. 10.6.0) will almost certainly be missing drivers for the new hardware.  The MacBook should've come with disks that include the needed drivers...

Comment: I'm not talking about missing drivers but the wrong architecture. It unlikely that Apple ships the wrong disks, though.

The message shown above is triggered by a kernel panic. That means that the kernel detected a fault and can't recover from it. E.g. because of wrong code (for other machines/architectures), programming errors or hardware failiures (e.g. RAM).